# Retrieved data from site using BeautifulSoup is different than data displayed on site

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests

A use the following code to web-scrape shoe information off "https://www.adidas.com/us/men-shoes" :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
import requests

uri = "men-shoes"
hdr = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36'}
html_page = requests.get("https://www.adidas.com/us/" + str(uri), headers=hdr, timeout=15)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page.content, 'html.parser')
results = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'gl-product-card color-variations__fixed-size glass-product-card___17N3p'})
```

Here is an example of the data i get while web scraping a particular shoe:

```
<div class="gl-product-card color-variations__fixed-size glass-product-card___17N3p">
    <div class="gl-product-card__assets">
        <a class="gl-product-card__assets-link" data-auto-id="glass-hockeycard-link" href="/us/superstar-shoes/FV2820.html">
            <img
                alt="Originals Black Superstar Shoes"
                class="img_with_fallback___2aHBu gl-product-card__image"
                data-auto-id="image"
                src="https://assets.adidas.com/images/w_385,h_385,f_auto,q_auto:sensitive,fl_lossy/3c086bf61062470aa54cab8700b26add_9366/superstar-shoes.jpg"
                title="Superstar Shoes"
            />
            <img
                alt="Originals Black Superstar Shoes"
                class="img_with_fallback___2aHBu gl-product-card__image-hover"
                data-auto-id="image"
                src="https://assets.adidas.com/images/w_385,h_385,f_auto,q_auto:sensitive,fl_lossy/d04a49435d094fcfa8dfab960070f1a9_9366/superstar-shoes.jpg"
                title="Superstar Shoes"
            />
        </a>
        <div class="gl-product-card__wishlist">
            <div class="toggle_wishlist_button___1dG52" data-auto-id="wishlist-icon-container">
                <svg class="gl-icon" data-auto-id="wishlist-icon"><use xlink:href="#wishlist-inactive"></use></svg>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="gl-product-card__carousel">
        <div class="product-carousel" data-auto-id="glass-mock-carousel">
            <div class="wrapper___3wqg4">
                <div class="item_wrapper___2toNm"></div>
                <div class="item_wrapper___2toNm"></div>
                <div class="item_wrapper___2toNm"></div>
                <div class="item_wrapper___2toNm"></div>
                <div class="item_wrapper___2toNm"></div>
                <div class="item_wrapper___2toNm"></div>
                <div class="item_wrapper___2toNm"></div>
                <div class="item_wrapper___2toNm"></div>
                <div class="item_wrapper___2toNm"></div>
                <div class="item_wrapper___2toNm"></div>
                <div class="item_wrapper___2toNm"></div>
                <div class="item_wrapper___2toNm"></div>
                <div class="item_wrapper___2toNm"></div>
                <div class="item_wrapper___2toNm"></div>
                <div class="item_wrapper___2toNm"></div>
                <div class="item_wrapper___2toNm"></div>
                <div class="item_wrapper___2toNm"></div>
                <div class="item_wrapper___2toNm"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="gl-product-card__details">
        <a class="gl-product-card__details-link" href="/us/superstar-shoes/FV2820.html">
            <div class="gl-product-card__details-top">
                <div class="gl-product-card__category" title="shoes">Originals</div>
                <div class="gl-product-card__details-icons"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="gl-product-card__details-main">
                <span class="gl-label gl-label--m gl-label--condensed gl-product-card__name" title="Superstar Shoes">Superstar Shoes</span>
                <div class="gl-price gl-price--s gl-price__inline___-VD1g notranslate"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="gl-product-card__details-bottom"><div class="gl-product-card__color">18 colors</div></div>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the data I get when I copy a shoe directly from the website:

```
<div class="gl-product-card color-variations__fixed-size glass-product-card___17N3p">
    <div class="gl-product-card__assets">
        <a data-auto-id="glass-hockeycard-link" href="/us/zx-2k-4d-shoes/FW2003.html" class="gl-product-card__assets-link" data-di-id="di-id-93927325-c0dba7aa">
            <img
                data-auto-id="image"
                title="ZX 2K 4D Shoes"
                src="https://assets.adidas.com/images/w_385,h_385,f_auto,q_auto:sensitive,fl_lossy/d704fc8256204415b713ab6600f76418_9366/zx-2k-4d-shoes.jpg"
                alt="Originals White ZX 2K 4D Shoes"
                class="img_with_fallback___2aHBu gl-product-card__image performance-item"
                data-inject_ssr_performance_instrument=""
                onload="SSR_PERFORMANCE_MEASUREMENT(this)"
            />
            <img
                data-auto-id="image"
                title="ZX 2K 4D Shoes"
                src="https://assets.adidas.com/images/w_385,h_385,f_auto,q_auto:sensitive,fl_lossy/e169facc2c554c21b9d1ab880150342a_9366/zx-2k-4d-shoes.jpg"
                alt="Originals White ZX 2K 4D Shoes"
                class="img_with_fallback___2aHBu gl-product-card__image-hover"
            />
        </a>
        <div class="gl-product-card__wishlist">
            <div class="toggle_wishlist_button___1dG52" data-auto-id="wishlist-icon-container">
                <svg class="gl-icon" data-auto-id="wishlist-icon" data-di-res-id="d45e29bb-1d8adc35" data-di-rand="1596955983257"><use xlink:href="#wishlist-inactive"></use></svg>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="gl-badge gl-badge--small gl-badge--semi-urgent">New</div>
    </div>
    <div class="gl-product-card__details">
        <a href="/us/zx-2k-4d-shoes/FW2003.html" class="gl-product-card__details-link" data-di-id="di-id-93927325-c0dba7aa">
            <div class="gl-product-card__details-top">
                <div class="gl-product-card__category" title="shoes">Originals</div>
                <div class="gl-product-card__details-icons"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="gl-product-card__details-main">
                <span class="gl-label gl-label--m gl-label--condensed gl-product-card__name" title="ZX 2K 4D Shoes">ZX 2K 4D Shoes</span>
                <div class="gl-price gl-price--s gl-price__inline___-VD1g notranslate"><span class="gl-price__value">$200</span></div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see from the site and copied data it shows the price, in this case $200. How do I get my code to show the price of the shoe?

Please include time optimized code, since I have to scrape over a hundred shoes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For that particular site, you'll probably have a better time simply accessing the JSON API they use for data. That way you don't have to scrape anything, just parse the JSON and read it

Looking at the Network inspector for the site,

- e.g. https://www.adidas.com/api/plp/content-engine?sitePath=us&query=men-shoes seems to return a list of items on each page
- e.g. https://www.adidas.com/api/search/product/FW2003?sitePath=us seems to return the information for a given product, including its price.

Answer (score 2):

The webpage you are scraping is loading its prices in dynamically after the page loads with javascript. BeautifulSoup only deals with HTML, so the easy way to solve this is to load the webpage linked to each card and get the shoe price from there, as the product page for each product doesn't dynamically load their prices. A more lightweight way is to use the site's JSON API.

In this case, you can load the product IDs for each product from the product listing, then request its information from the site's JSON API at https://www.adidas.com/api/search/product/FW2003, for product FW2003. From that JSON you can construct a dictionary using Python's requests module.

For instance:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
import requests

uri = "men-shoes"
hdr = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36'}
html_page = requests.get("https://www.adidas.com/us/" + str(uri), headers=hdr, timeout=15)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page.content, 'html.parser')
results = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'grid-item___eaXVb'})
ids = []

for res in results:
    ids.append(res.get['data-grid-id'])

for id in ids:
    url = "https://www.adidas.com/api/search/product/" + id
    res = requests.get(url)
    price = res.json()['price']
    ...
```

Comment: Is there a more time effective method? I need to get nearly 100 shoes

Comment: This doesnt seem to work. Did you mean to use 'div' instead of 'a'?

Answer (score 2):

The beauty of this website is all the products in a page are stored in a javascript variable called - `DATA_STORE`. If you can get that variable value, you get the basic information about the product. But as prices are associated with discounts and time period, the website makes an ajax call everytime you scroll down the page like lazy loading.

Once you get the productIds you have to make an ajax call with every productId to get the price information.

The following script gets all the product data from the page, gets the price information and stores it to a json. Once, you have the json, it's easy to parse the json

Note*: To construct json out of the javascript variable, it's a bit tricky. You need to encode and decode to remove the backslashes which the script takes care of.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
import requests, sys, json, time

uri = "men-shoes"
hdr = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36'}
html_page = requests.get("https://www.adidas.com/us/" + str(uri), headers=hdr, timeout=15)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page.content, 'html.parser')

script = None
for i in soup.find_all("script"):
    if "DATA_STORE" in i.text.strip():
        script = i.text.strip()
        break

if script is None:
    print("no data found")
    sys.exit(1)

all_items = json.loads(script[script.index("{"):-3].encode().decode('unicode_escape'))

data = {}

for item in all_items['plp']['itemList']['items']:
    print(item["productId"])
    res = requests.get("https://www.adidas.com/api/search/product/{}?sitePath=us".format(item["productId"]), headers=hdr, timeout=15)
    data[item["productId"]] = res.json()
    time.sleep(1)

print(data)

with open("data.json", "w") as f:
    json.dump(data,f)
```

Output:

```
{'FW2003': {'price': 200, 'badgeStyle': '', 'badgeText': '', 'cached': False, 'salePrice': 200, 'image': {'src': 'https://assets.adidas.com/images/w_280,h_280,f_auto,q_auto:sensitive/d704fc8256204415b713ab6600f76418_9366/zx-2k-4d-shoes.jpg', 'cloudinary': True}, 'secondImage': {'src': 'https://assets.adidas.com/images/w_280,h_280,f_auto,q_auto:sensitive/e169facc2c554c21b9d1ab880150342a_9366/zx-2k-4d-shoes.jpg', 'cloudinary': True}, 'color': 'Cloud White / Core Black / Signal Pink', 'modelId': 'KYU21', 'orderable': True, 'validFrom': {'default@adidas-PE': '2020-07-01T03:00:00.000Z', 'default@adidas-CL': '2020-07-15T04:00:00.000Z', 'default@adidas-MX': '2020-10-01T17:00:00.000Z', 'default@adidas-CO': '2020-07-15T03:00:00.000Z', 'default@adidas-US': '2020-07-10T07:00:00.000Z', 'default@adidas-BR': '2020-07-01T03:00:00.000Z', 'default@adidas-AR': '2020-07-15T03:00:00.000Z'}, 'previewTo': '2020-07-13T07:00:00.000Z', 'isFlash': False, 'isFinalSale': False, 'isSpecialLaunch': False, 'id': 'FW2003', 'link': '/us/zx-2k-4d-shoes/FW2003.html'}, 'FX7847': {'price': 140, 'badgeStyle': '', 'badgeText': '', 'cached': False, 'salePrice': 140, 'image': {'src': 'https://assets.adidas.com/images/w_280,h_280,f_auto,q_auto:sensitive/5fba111ccaab411a9171ab57000ec9e8_9366/climacool-vento-shoes.jpg', 'cloudinary': True}, 'secondImage': {'src': 'https://assets.adidas.com/images/w_280,h_280,f_auto,q_auto:sensitive/77e6c85bc38d40e6a912ab52017d1197_9366/climacool-vento-shoes.jpg', 'cloudinary': True}, 'color': 'Signal Cyan / Orbit Grey / Signal Pink', 'modelId': 'LDT02', 'orderable': True, 'validFrom': {'default@adidas-CA': '2020-06-01T05:00:00.000Z', 'default@adidas-US': '2020-05-31T07:00:00.000Z'}, 'previewTo': '2020-06-01T07:00:00.000Z', 'isFlash': False, 'isFinalSale': False, 'isSpecialLaunch': False, 'id': 'FX7847', 'link': '/us/climacool-vento-shoes/FX7847.html'}, 'B42200': {'price': 140, 'badgeStyle': '', 'badgeText': '', 'cached': False, 'salePrice': 140, 'image': {'src': 'https://assets.adidas.com/images/w_280,h_280,f_auto,q_auto:sensitive/de7d57ddae474f139736a8ba00fcbfb8_9366/nmd_r1-shoes.jpg', 'cloudinary': True}, 'secondImage': {'src': 'https://assets.adidas.com/images/w_280,h_280,f_auto,q_auto:sensitive/ad3348fcdb5f40a0b410a8ba00fc6427_9366/nmd_r1-shoes.jpg', 'cloudinary': True}, 'color': 'Black / Black / Gum', 'modelId': 'BSZ68', 'orderable': True, 'validFrom': {'default': '2018-07-01T04:00:00.000Z', 'default@adidas-PE': '2018-07-01T03:00:00.000Z', 'default@adidas-CL': '2018-07-01T04:00:00.000Z', 'default@adidas-MX': '2018-07-01T05:00:00.000Z', 'default@adidas-CO': '2018-07-01T03:00:00.000Z', 'default@adidas-CA': '2018-06-01T05:00:00.000Z', 'default@adidas-US': '2018-06-01T07:00:00.000Z', 'default@adidas-BR': '2018-07-01T03:00:00.000Z', 'default@adidas-AR': '2019-04-01T03:00:00.000Z'}, 'previewTo': '2012-12-11T22:00:00.000Z', 'isFlash': False, 'isFinalSale': False, 'isSpecialLaunch': False, 'id': 'B42200', 'link': '/us/nmd_r1-shoes/B42200.html'}, 'EF1042': {'price': 180, 'badgeStyle': '', 'badgeText': '', 'cached': False, 'salePrice': 180, 'image': {'src': 'https://assets.adidas.com/images/w_280,h_280,f_auto,q_auto:sensitive/1e74db8746cd492b9814aafc0106ac2d_9366/ultraboost-20-shoes.jpg', 'cloudinary': True}, 'secondImage': {'src': 'https://assets.adidas.com/images/w_280,h_280,f_auto,q_auto:sensitive/c6c5c2caafc8405b8e4baaff00e21e50_9366/ultraboost-20-shoes.jpg', 'cloudinary': True}, 'color': 'Cloud White / Cloud White / Core Black', 'modelId': 'DVF21', 'orderable': True, 'validFrom': {'default@adidas-CA': '2020-01-01T06:00:00.000Z', 'default@adidas-US': '2020-01-01T08:00:00.000Z'}, 'previewTo': '2012-12-11T22:00:00.000Z', 'isFlash': False, 'isFinalSale': False, 'isSpecialLaunch': False, 'id': 'EF1042', 'link': '/us/ultraboost-20-shoes/EF1042.html'}, 'M20324': {'price': 80, 'badgeStyle': '', 'badgeText': '', 'cached': False, 'salePrice': 80, 'image': {'src': 'https://assets.adidas.com/images/w_280,h_280,f_auto,q_auto:sensitive/25c70a990dd74210aa47a59900ebfe5d_9366/stan-smith-shoes.jpg', 'cloudinary': True}, 'secondImage': {'src': 'https://assets.adidas.com/images/w_280,h_280,f_auto,q_auto:sensitive/f7f13f58f83e46698f15aacb01622c54_9366/stan-smith-shoes.jpg', 'cloudinary': True}, 'color': 'Cloud White / Core White / Green', 'modelId': 'ION05', 'orderable': True, 'validFrom': {'default': '2017-08-08T03:00:00.000Z', 'default@adidas-PE': '2017-05-01T03:00:00.000Z', 'default@adidas-CL': '2016-07-05T04:00:00.000Z', 'default@adidas-MX': '2017-01-01T06:00:00.000Z', 'default@adidas-CO': '2016-01-15T02:00:00.000Z', 'default@adidas-CA': '2015-01-27T06:00:00.000Z', 'default@adidas-US': '2014-01-15T08:00:00.000Z', 'default@adidas-BR': '2020-02-11T03:00:00.000Z', 'default@adidas-AR': '2017-08-08T03:00:00.000Z'}, 'previewTo': '2012-12-11T22:00:00.000Z', 'isFlash': False, 'isFinalSale': False, 'isSpecialLaunch': False, 'id': 'M20324', 'link': '/us/stan-smith-shoes/M20324.html'}}
...
...
...
```

To get prices:

```
for k,v in a.items():
    print(f"ProductId - {k}")
    print("Price - {}".format(v["price"]))
    print("Sale Price - {}".format(v["salePrice"]))
    print("---"*20)
```

Output:

```
ProductId - FW2003
Price - 200
Sale Price - 200
------------------------------------------------------------
ProductId - FX7847
Price - 140
Sale Price - 140
------------------------------------------------------------
ProductId - B42200
Price - 140
Sale Price - 140
------------------------------------------------------------
ProductId - EF1042
Price - 180
Sale Price - 180
------------------------------------------------------------
ProductId - M20324
Price - 80
Sale Price - 80
------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: The line where you parsed the script onto text made my day!!, Thanks alot.

Comment: why we did encode then decode?